# finding irrational positive eigenvalues of a real symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, real-numbers, symmetry

I have a real symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrix and I know all its eigenvalues are positive and irrational. All I care about are the eigenvalues (don't need the eigenvectors).

What is the most efficient way to do this? Speed and accuracy both matter, since this calculation will be repeated billions of time in a code.

Comment: Technically, you can use the cubic formula to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, but it is probably easier to use a standard symmetric eigenvalue solver (see LAPACK for instance).

Comment: the lapack routines are designed to work efficiently for large matrices and for a 3x3 matrix its rather slow (since this needs to be repeated more than billions of time). Also trying to find the roots of the cubic equations seems unreliable and not always accurate.

Comment: The cubic formula will always give you the correct answer, the issue is that there are some places in the formula where catastrophic cancellations are possible. Anyway, are you sure you were using a symmetric solver when you tried LAPACK? The symmetric solver should be quite fast on 3x3 cases (I'd be surprised if it took even 50 ms).

Comment: initially i was using the cubic root method and for many cases it was resulting in inaccurate final answers (pretty much for the reason you mentioned).  For the lapack routines, I was using 'dspev' and it was significantly slower than the cubic method (took more than 10 times !)

Answer (score 1):

The strategy I would personally use is

0) Compute the characteristic polynomial $\chi(\lambda)$.

1) Separate its roots $\lambda_i (i=1, 2, 3)$ by certain $\mu_i (i=1,  2)$ i.e., have

$$0<\lambda_1<\mu_1< \lambda_2<\mu_2<\lambda_3$$

This can be done easily by taking for the $\mu_i$ the eigenvalues of the $2 \times 2$ upper diagonal block of the matrix (interlacing theorem).

2) Take a rather slow method in order to get closer to one of the roots (some steps of dichotomy are not ridiculous), for example $\lambda_1$.

3) Then, refine this root by Newton's method.

4) Then divide $\chi(\lambda)$ by $(\lambda-\lambda_1)$ to get a second degree polynomial whose roots are $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$. No fear of serious loss of accuracy in this operation in such low size matrices.

Remark: An alternative for finding the first root $\lambda_1$: use the Laguerre's method (see "Numerical Recipes").

Comment: I am currently resorting to using a similar approach. I am finding the largest eigenvalue by using power iteration and then using that to solve for the roots of a second order polynomial. For now this seems like the fastest approach. Thanks for the suggestion !